# Are there mixed radix "p-adic" rings?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I tried looking for something about this, but I couldn't seem to find anything so maybe I'm using the wrong terminology or maybe the idea is fundamentally flawed in a way I've not considered yet.

So just to give a concrete example to help clarify, turn the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) into "n!-adic integers", then for instance I would expect something like this to converge for appropriate values of $x \in$ "$\mathbb{Z}_{n!}$",

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{\varphi(n!)}-1}{n!}$$

I can clarify further, I realize I'm being quite terse and presumptuous but I'm more focused on getting on the right track for finding a mixed radix version of p-adics, the example is just a vague idea.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like the inverse limit of the $\Bbb Z/n!\Bbb Z$? I reckon that is $\hat{\Bbb Z}$, the profinite closure of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I think so as far as the inverse limit is concerned I think that's what I'm looking for. I've heard the word "profinite" thrown around a few times in the past so I guess that's what I'll look into. Thanks.